# Solutions of the equation: $x\cos(\pi y)=y\cos(\pi x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to find the solutions $y=f(x)$ of the equation:
$$x\cos(\pi y)=y\cos(\pi x)$$
in $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})$. Is it possible to solve it analytically or I should use only numerical methods?
Thanks

Comment: What can you say about $h(z) = \dfrac{z}{\cos (\pi z)}$ on the interval $[0,\frac12)$?

Comment: Obviously in the point $z=0.5$ there is a singularity

Comment: Take arc cos on both sides and solve?

Comment: @RnjaiLamba: $\arccos(x\cos(\pi y)))$?

Comment: Yes you can try solving like this.